# Csv Parser is not reading correctly when value is having comma

Tags: java, apache, opencsv

I have to parse a CSV. I am using Apache common csv to do the same.My csv structures data looks like :

```
Name, ErrorType, Location,    Error Detail,                Mandatory
ABC , E1       , "XYZ\ABC",  "Valid Values: 'X','Y','Z'",  REQUIRED
```

I am using below configuration for csv Parser

```
CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withIgnoreSurroundingSpaces()                        
                 .withQuote(null).
                 .withHeader(excelHeaders)
                 .withFirstRecordAsHeader().parse(in).getRecords();
```

I have to use withQuote(null) option to avoid error

```
java.io.IOException: (line 27) invalid char between encapsulated token and delimiter
at org.apache.commons.csv.Lexer.parseEncapsulatedToken(Lexer.java:281)
at org.apache.commons.csv.Lexer.nextToken(Lexer.java:158)
at org.apache.commons.csv.CSVParser.nextRecord(CSVParser.java:586)
at org.apache.commons.csv.CSVParser.getRecords(CSVParser.java:448)
```

It is giving me the details of Error Detail column whenever I am trying to read the value of Mandatory column .

Is there any way to ignore the comma inside the quotes, I have already tried withEscape('"') .If I use this, I got an exception that csv doesn't have this index.

Answer (score 0):

As a kinda hacky solution you could 'parse' the CSV beforehand eg with regex.

You could manually replace the commata with other chars, if they are inside of the quotes.

But I think there would be nicer options to solve this. But if you just need a fast way of doing it, that should work.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you remove the withQuote(altogether as by default it is a Quote)

```
CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withIgnoreSurroundingSpaces()                        
                 .withHeader(excelHeaders)
                 .withFirstRecordAsHeader().parse(in).getRecords();
```

What gets me about your stacktrace is if you look at the [actual apache commons csv code](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=commons-csv.git;a=blob;f=src/main/java/org/apache/commons/csv/Lexer.java;h=76fa81ee272f99939483e969fec2809b575e2fd1;hb=HEAD) you will see that the only way to get this exception is for it to identify a character as a quote character and then it looks ahead and sees that the next character is not a quote (and not a delimiter or whitespace) so it throws the above exception.  So that tells me the withQuote(null) did not work - which I don't think you want anyway because some characters do not have quotes or your parser did not get your format.